# Input dentro de Tabla con columnas y filas dinámicas en Angular

Tags: angular, bootstrap

Tengo un formulario con dos input `columnas` y `filas`
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y a través de estos dos datos creo una tabla de nxn y las relleno con datos aleatorios en una tabla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y quiero también tener la opción de ingresar los datos manuales, de esta forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pero como las filas y las columnas las agrego de forma dinámica, no se como crear un identificador para para cada input de esa tabla y enviarlas por medio de un `NgForm` a un método.

Así lo estoy manejando con los datos aleatorios:

```
    <form (ngSubmit)="ejecutarModelos(g.value)" #g="ngForm" *ngIf="mostrarMatriz && datos.manual">
  <h4 class="display-6">Matriz Manual:</h4>
  <table class="table table-bordered jumbotron">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th scope="col">#</th>
        <th scope="col" *ngFor="let columna of arrayColumnas">Col. {{columna}}</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr *ngFor="let fila of arrayFilas">
        <th>Fila {{fila}}</th>
        <td *ngFor="let obj of td.arrayRandom">{{obj[fila]}}</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</form>



  ejecutarRandom(f: NgForm) {
this.resultadoLagrange = f.value.columnas;
let nColumnas = 1 / f.value.columnas;
this.arrayColumnas = [];
this.arrayFilas = [];

for (let index = 1; index <= f.value.filas; index++) {
  this.arrayFilas.push(index);
}

for (let index = 1; index <= f.value.columnas; index++) {
  this.arrayColumnas.push(index);
  let obj = {}

  for (let index = 1; index <= this.arrayFilas.length; index++) {

    let first = index;
    obj[first] = this.getRandom(f.value.rangoMin, f.value.rangoMax);
  }

  this.td.arrayRandom.push(obj)

}

   this.td.arrayLagrnage = [...this.td.arrayRandom]
this.metotodoLagrange(this.td.arrayLagrnage, nColumnas);
this.mostrarMatriz = true;

};
```

Answer (score 1):

La idea es crear primero  un arreglo de columnas. Luego crear las filas, considerando el número de columnas.

Para que se pueda editar la celda hay que agregar un input y hacer un model binding con el valor del objeto de esa celda. Y cuando no esté editando hay que mostrar directamente el valor con una interpolación.

Para lograr eso se agregan dos div dentro del td, uno  para contener el input y el otro para contener la interpolación y se muestra uno o el otro dependiendo del valor de la propiedad `editar` del objeto de la celda.

A cada celda se le agrega un evento `click`, que al dispararse llama la función `ocultarCeldas()` la cual recorre toda la tabla y establece la propiedad `editar` de todos los objetos de las celdas a false y habilita la edición de la celda donde se produjo el evento.

[Demo en vivo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-q7xh6p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  template: `
    <table border="1">
      <th *ngFor="let col of columnas">{{ col }}</th>
      <tr *ngFor="let fila of filas">
        <td *ngFor="let celda of fila" (click)="ocultarCeldas(celda)">
          <div *ngIf="celda.editar">
            <input
              type="text"
              [(ngModel)]="celda.valor"
              (blur)="celda.editar = false"
            />
          </div>
          <div *ngIf="!celda.editar">
            {{ celda.valor }}
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  `
})
export class AppComponent {
  filas = [];
  columnas = [];

  constructor() {
    this.llenarAleatorio();
  }

  llenarAleatorio() {
    // entre 1 y 10
    let totalColumnas = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

    // crear las columnas
    for (let i = 0; i < totalColumnas; i++) {
      this.columnas.push(i);
    }

    //crear las filas entre 1 y 10
    let totalFilas = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10 + 1);

    for (let i = 0; i < totalFilas; i++) {
      let fila = [];

      for (let i = 0; i < totalColumnas; i++) {
        fila[i] = {
          valor: Math.floor(Math.random() * 100 + 1),
          editar: false
        };
      }
      this.filas.push(fila);
    }
  }

  ocultarCeldas(celda) {
    celda.editar = true;
    this.filas.forEach(f => {
      f.forEach(c => {
        if (c != celda) c.editar = false;
      });
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Voy a intentarlo y te comento como me va